# What is the DSL version of int-jms:inbound-gateway request-destination

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I am trying to create an app that will listen to JMS queue, process message and sends response to another JMS queue. As I understood the docs I can use JMS inbound gateway and some handler to process the request, something like this:

```java
IntegrationFlows.from(Jms.inboundGateway(connectionFactory).defaultReplyQueueName(responseQueue)).handle(handler).get();
```

However I don't know how to set the input JMS queue via DSL. I found that via XML it can be done as following:

```xml
<int-jms:inbound-gateway id="jmsInGateway"
    request-destination="inQueue"
    request-channel="exampleChannel"/>
```

Sadly `Jms.inboundGateway()` does not allow to set request destination. How can I set it?

Answer (score 1):

There are these two options for destination on that `Spec`:

```
    /**
     * @param destination the destination
     * @return the spec.
     * @see JmsListenerContainerSpec#destination(Destination)
     */
    public JmsInboundGatewayListenerContainerSpec<S, C> destination(Destination destination) {
        this.spec.destination(destination);
        return _this();
    }

    /**
     * @param destinationName the destinationName
     * @return the spec.
     * @see JmsListenerContainerSpec#destination(String)
     */
    public JmsInboundGatewayListenerContainerSpec<S, C> destination(String destinationName) {
        this.spec.destination(destinationName);
        return _this();
    }
```

So, your code snippet works for me like this:

```
return IntegrationFlows.from(
                Jms.inboundGateway(connectionFactory)
                        .destination("inQueue")
                        .defaultReplyQueueName(responseQueue))
                .handle(handler)
                .get();
```

I'm not sure why is that not visible for you...

On the other hand I see your point. It is probably better to name that option as a `requestDestination` for consistency with the `replyQueueName` and the same option in the XML DSL. Feel free to raise a GH issue or even provide a contribution on the matter deprecating an existing `destination` option!

Comment: See the fix here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/3494